# Spring Boot Jar Execution internal properties files

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, executable-jar, properties-file

I have a Spring Boot application that runs properly when I run it from Intellij as maven configurations.

I have a project structure of environments that is defined with properties files.

```
resources/conf/dev/environment.properties
resources/conf/qa/environment.properties
resources/conf/general.properties
```

etc.

Our framework works in a way that we are choosing the env with VM arguments.
for example `-Denv=dev` or `-Denv=qa`

After packaging the App to an executable JAR and trying to run it, Spring Boot can't identify the properties files under `conf` path of the project.

When I look inside the JAR the properties files are under `{jar-name}.jar\BOOT-INF\classes\conf`.

The error is:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: conf\general.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)`

```
2017-07-11 10:52:52.864  INFO 17896 --- [main] n.lifecycle: Can't find configuration file [conf\general.properties]
2017-07-11 10:52:52.865 ERROR 17896 --- [main] n.lifecycle: configuration file [null] not found (use default properties as error handling)
```

I've tried to work with the documentaion here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html
but nothing seems to fix it.
Also tried to work with this guide - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-launching but also failed...

The guides are referring to the properties files as "external" but my properties are packed in the JAR.

Comment: You should have : 
resources/conf/application-dev.properties
resources/conf/application-ga.properties
resources/conf/application.properties

I think this is spring expect to find

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. When I run the project before packaging it with "spring-boot:run" it's working properly.
Changing the names of the files will break our in-house framework for managing properties.

Comment: you run specific configuration from your IDE ? or just rigth clic the spring boot main class ?

Comment: No right click. Maven Run Configuration where the command line has spring-boot:run -Denv=dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out what's wrong.
Our in-house framework that's loading the resources are using `File.separator` to read the path of the resources.

Now for some reason when the jar is created with maven spring boot plugin the classpath is built with '/' for example `/C:/Users/MyUser/Projects/MyApp/target/MyApp-1.0.1.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/` (the resources are in classes path inside of the jar of course)

And when we are trying to run the jar it's trying to read the resources with '\' so the path that is built is (if we choose "dev" for example) `/C:/Users/MyUser/Projects/MyApp/target/MyApp-1.0.1.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/`**conf\dev** and that is why the app is failing to load.

I still don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put properties files in resources.
Not in resources / conf.
It works so well.